# Telerik - Rad Combob Box - Jquery - OnSelectedIndexChange

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web-applications, telerik

how can i fire telerik rad combo box selectedindexchange event With Jquery...
My Pages Base on Master And Content Pages And In Content Pages I have multiviews And inside Multiviews I have RadComboBoxes

i had some problem about getting controls in content pages (inside multiviews)...
best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ClientID of the control - use it as a jquery selector.
Instead of using it in Telerik style selector:

```
var telerikCombo = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
```

Use it as a jQuery selector:

```
var jqueryCombo = $("#<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");
```